# Null Exception on VideoView in Fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to make a videoview that would display on fragment.

```
VideoView videoView;

public First_Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    Button button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);

    videoView = (VideoView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video);
    String path = "android.resource://"+getActivity().getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.tutorial;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_, container, false);
}
```

But everytime I run it, it always gives me a Null Exception error.

```
    05-04 15:20:50.446 6567-6567/luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial, PID: 6567
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial.First_Fragment.onCreateView(First_Fragment.java:41)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   05-04 15:20:52.840 6567-6567/luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6567 SIG: 9
   05-04 15:35:33.638 6694-6694/luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial-2/lib/x86
   05-04 15:35:33.934 6694-6694/luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial W/art: Verification of void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(android.content.Context, android.view.Window, android.support.v7.app.AppCompatCallback) took 208.216ms
   05-04 15:35:34.912 6694-6694/luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
   05-04 15:35:35.025 6694-6736/luisanthony.androidstudiotutorial D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

Comment: Inflate the view before return, then find the views from the inflated view in onCreateView() method.

Comment: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_, container, false);  and use findviewbyid with 'v' and return 'v'

Comment: It works. Thanks for the help